# databinding fontweight silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I'm trying to bind FontWeight in datagrid to a property in code and getting a xamlparseexception. This is the code

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn                         
                        Header="Date" 
                        CellStyle="{StaticResource ListColumnStyle}"
                        Binding="{Binding Date}"
                        FontWeight="{Binding StatusToFont}"
                        IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

and the property is defined as

```
public FontWeight StatusToFont 
        {
            get
            {
                return FontWeights.SemiBold;
            }
        }
```

Anyone sees any issue in this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **DataGridTextColumn** does not support bindings on FontWeight, cause it´s not a DependencyProperty.

A workaraound is to use a **DataGridTemplateColumn** and specify a **TextBox** as DataTemplate. On the TextBox you can apply any bindings that are supported on a TextBox.

```
  <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" 
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource ListColumnStyle}"
                    Binding="{Binding Date}"
                    IsReadOnly="True">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding StatusToFont}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```